# How to detect a page reload inside a vue app and redirect the user

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to detect a page reload inside a vue app (to avoid loss of in-memory data), and redirect the user after asking him what to do (continue/cancel) to a given page, through vue-router?

This code below works in detecting the reload, but if I put it in main.js, I cannot use the router, and if I put it in App.vue (I'm using a vue-cli 3.0 project), the user is redirected but all in-memory data are gone for good...

```
switch(performance.navigation.type) {
   case 0:
     console.info("TYPE_NAVIGATE");
     break;
   case 1:
     console.info("TYPE_RELOAD");
     alert('reload')
     this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
     break;
   case 2:
     console.info("TYPE_BACK_FORWARD");
     break;
   case 255:
     console.info("255");
     break;
}
```

Comment: could you provide some tried code ?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim done! in fact the aim is to block the user before the in-memory data are gone, and if the user decides to backtrack he will remain authenticated, etc.